# Detecting middle mouse click event jQuery

Tags: jquery, click, mouseevent

I want to show a jQuery-UI dialog box as a popup when user clicks on left mouse button or the middle one. It works for left click (I get the alert box and after that the popup) but doesn't work for middle (neither alert box nor popup). What am I missing?

```js
$('a.external').live('click', function(e){
  if( e.which <= 2 ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert ("inside if");
  }
  popUp.start(this);
});
```

Comment: Tried on Chrome, FF and IE10.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `mousedown` or `mouseup` instead of `click`. And (unless you are using a *very* old version of jQuery) use `.on()` instead of `.live()`:

```
$(document).on("mousedown", "a.external", function(e) {
   if( e.which <= 2 ) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert ("inside if");
   }
   popUp.start(this);
});
```

...where ideally you'd use a parent element much closer to the link than `document`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7S2SQ/

Comment: Why are you passing `"a.external"` as data to the event handler? Wasn't he using that as the selector?

Comment: @Nate - I'm not passing `"a.external"` as data, that _is_ the selector for a delegated event. Have a look at the [`.on()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/). In this case the mousedown event is bound to the document, but when it occurs jQuery automatically checks if the source element matches the selector in that second argument (and only calls your function if it does match). Ideally you wouldn't bind to the document: as mentioned in my answer ideally you'd use a parent element closer to the link.

Comment: Thanks. (e.witch == 2) means middle button, just in case.

Comment: @LucasBustamante - Yes, the alert has nothing to do with the mouse event, it's just there for demonstration purposes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the alert is necessary in this case for the browser to allow you to bypass the native functionality of middle-mouse click

Comment: @LucasBustamante - No, you definitely don't need an alert: http://jsfiddle.net/7S2SQ/156/ - as far as bypassing the native functionality, that's what `e.preventDefault()` does.

Comment: @LucasBustamante - Oh, right. In that case the `alert()` doesn't stop the default behavior either, in that the default behavior of opening the link appears to happen on the `mouseup` event, not `mousedown` and `e.preventDefault()` doesn't seem to stop that. The only reason `alert()` *seems* to stop that is that if you close the alert using the mouse then the anchor doesn't receive a `mouseup` event at all (because you've moved the mouse to the alert). If you click the mouse button down, then close the alert with the keyboard, then let go of the mouse button the default behavior continues.

Comment: I got the same result with mouseup

Comment: @JorgeOlivares - unless you're talking about pointed hats and broomsticks, I think you'll find it's `e.which == 2` ;-)

Comment: @freefaller just realized that I made a typo haha

Answer (score 5):

To get this working fully in Firefox (40.0.3), I had to implement `.on('mouseup', fn)`, as follows:

```
$(selector).on('mouseup', function (e) {

    switch (e.which)
    {
        // Left Click.
        case 1:
            // By way of example, I've added Ctrl+Click Modifiers.
            if (e.ctrlKey) {
                // Ctrl+LeftClick behaviour.
            } else {
                // Standard LeftClick behaviour.
            }
            break;

        // Middle click.
        case 2:
            // Interrupts "Firefox Open New Tab" behaviour.
            break;

        // Default behaviour for right click.
        case 3:
            return;
    }

    // Pass control back to default handler.
    return true;
});
```

Comment: @nnnnnn, thank you for the edit. I don't know how I missed that. :-S