# jQuery's delegated events can't cancel middle clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-events, event-propagation

The following code cancels left clicks and middle clicks on the whole page:

```
<script> $(document).on('click',false) </script>
<a href="http://example.com">link</a>
```

This other code uses a jquery delegated event to cancel clicks on `A` elements only:

```
<script> $(document).on('click','a',false) </script>
<a href="http://example.com">link</a>
```

which works fine for left clicks, but if you middle click the link, a new tab is opened, which means the event was not cancelled.

Why using the second code, middle clicks are not cancellled?

Comment: `click` is the left button, by definition. you can use `mousedown`

Comment: @dandavis, first time I hear that. Where is that documented?

Comment: Detecting middle click: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5393604/816620 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130852/detecting-middle-mouse-click-event-jquery

Comment: i don't know where it's documented, but that's always been the way it is...

Comment: @dandavis, then why the first code can cancel middle clicks just fine?

Comment: i suspect that click is synthetic on A tags. for example, pressing [Enter] on a <button> also raises button.click(). it's probably too late to cancel the delegated event by the time it bubbles up to document. you can use your first handler and inspect `e.target.tagName` to screen A tags...

Comment: @dandavis, I included the first code to show that it's not too late to cancel an event when it bubbled all the way up to the document.

Comment: if my understanding of jq events is correct, the first one is not delegated, the click still "happens" on the A tag (during capturing phase). the delegated one uses a mother function (coded by jq) on document that examines the event args and executes jq-subscribed events that match criteria, so the event really "happens" on document, even if jq makes it appear otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery explicitly disallow non-left-clicks on delegated events, as can be seen on the source code, line 357:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1de834672959636da8c06263c3530226b17a84c3/src/event.js#L357

The reason:
Firefox doesn't support middle-click events, so they decided to disallow the feature for all browsers.

As a workarond, the expression

```
$(document).on('click','a',false)
```

can be converted to the functionaly equivalent

```
$(document).click(function(evt){ if($(evt.target).closest('a').length) return false })
```