# How can I execute a function for both left and middle click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```js
$('a').on('click', function(){
  myfunc($(this));
});

function myfunc(el){
  console.log('Either left or middle click clicked on the link');
}
```

```css
a{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>click</a>
```

My code works just for *left* click. How do I run that function when the users clicks on the link through the middle-click too?

Comment: Middle click? You mean scroll click?

Comment: yes exactly ...

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130852/detecting-middle-mouse-click-event-jquery)

Comment: Then this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392442/detect-middle-button-click-scroll-button-with-jquery. It says there that on mousedown event you can detect the middle click and do whatever you want in a condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting middle mouse click event jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130852/detecting-middle-mouse-click-event-jquery)

Comment: use mousedown or mouseup instead of click

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").on("mousedown", function(e){
    switch(e.which)
    {
        case 1:
            //left Click
        break;
        case 2:
            //middle Click
        break;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a').on('mousedown', function(e){
    if( e.which <= 2 ) {
        myfunc($(this));
    } 
});

function myfunc(el){
  console.log('Either left or middle click clicked on the link');
}
```