# jquery trigger middle mouse click does not work?

Tags: jquery, tampermonkey

The following Tampermonkey js works (wait for a link show up then click it):

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     converto.io click the download link
// @include    *://*.converto.io/en/download/*
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @run-at document-end
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.
/* global $, waitForKeyElements */

setTimeout(main, 1000);

function main(){
   waitForKeyElements ("#download-url", clickNode, true);
}

function clickNode (jNode) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

Now I want to change it to middle mouse click, I googled quite a while and assembled this following code, but it doesn't work, and there's no error alert.
Any idea? Appreciate any response.

```js
setTimeout(main, 1000);

function main(){
  waitForKeyElements ("#download-url", clickNode, true);
}

function clickNode (jNode) {
  if ( window.CustomEvent ) {
      var middleClick = new MouseEvent( "click", { "button": 1, "which": 1 });
      jNode[0].dispatchEvent( middleClick );
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting middle mouse click event jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130852/detecting-middle-mouse-click-event-jquery)

Comment: `which:2` will detect the middle button, if rest of the code is correct

Comment: @AniketG I know but I want to DO the click, not detect it - if I detected it's a middle button click, next step I still have to do middle click?

Comment: @Tushar Thanks, but both which:2 and button:2 which:2 don't work.

Comment: Oh yeah apologies, I missed that!

Comment: @user2650501 huh you want to do the click... I retracted my flag

Comment: Just a workaround thought pop up: can I make a modifcation to that link to force it open in new tab if clicked by left-mouse-button?

Comment: In the left-click version, I inserted "$("#download-url").attr("target","_blank");" before the last dispatchEvent line, and the result HTML is like:<a id="download-url" href="******" data-href="******" target="_blank" title="" style="">Click here</a>  Seems good? but it does not do the click. How so?

Comment: Browsers (Chrome at least) handle the middle-click internally so a synthetic click event is ignored. You can probably use GM_download or GM_openInTab instead.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks a lot, very helpful. Guess I need a little more time to figure this out.